# Using output of NDSolve to write function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm using NDSolve to solve a vector differential equation numerically. The equation has a few parameters, that I would like to be able to vary. I define the relevant parameters and equation as follows:

```
mR[t_] = {mRx[t], mRy[t], mRz[t]}; 
d[\[Phi]_] = {Sin[\[Phi]], 0, Cos[\[Phi]]}; mL = {0, 0, 1}; mR0 = 
 Normalize[{1, 1, 1}]; origin = {0, 0, 0};

sol[a_,b_,c_,\[Phi]_,tmax_]:=NDSolve[{mR'[t] == (mL + a  d[\[Phi]]\[Cross]mL + 
      b  d[\[Phi]]\[Cross]mR[t] + c  mR'[t])\[Cross]mR[t], 
  mR[0] == mR0}, mR[t], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

What I want to do is write another function that takes the solution, with the same input variables. I.e. something like making a parametric plot of the solution, with varying input parameters

```
plot[a_,b_,c_,\[Phi]_,tmax_]:=ParametricPlot3D[mR[t]/.sol[a,b,c,\[Phi],tmax][[1]],{t,0,tmax}]
```

However, when using this function, i.e. by running e.g. `plot[1,1,1,Pi,100]` I get an error. However, I get the desired plot if I write

```
solution=sol[1,1,1,Pi,100][[1]];
ParametricPlot3d[mR[t]/.solution,{t,0,100}]
```

but this requires me running multiple lines of code rather than just one. Does anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Comment: ParametricPlot has the attribute "HoldAll". This means, that `mR[t]/.sol[a,b,c,\[Phi],tmax][[1]]` is not evaluated. To force the evaluation, you need to write: `Evaluate[mR[t]/.sol[a,b,c,\[Phi],tmax][[1]]]`

Comment: This is described in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) (see the Applications section).

Comment: Thank you both, and thank you, Daniel for the solution. I only used the ParametricPlot3D command as an example (I had run into the same issue using other commands, so I didn't think the solution could be specific to the plot command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

mR[t_] = {mRx[t], mRy[t], mRz[t]};
d[ϕ_] = {Sin[ϕ], 0, Cos[ϕ]}; mL = {0, 0, 1}; mR0 = 
 Normalize[{1, 1, 1}]; origin = {0, 0, 0};

sol[a_, b_, c_, ϕ_, tmax_] := 
 NDSolve[{mR'[
     t] == (mL + a   d[ϕ]\[Cross]mL + b   d[ϕ]\[Cross]mR[t] + 
       c   mR'[t])\[Cross]mR[t], mR[0] == mR0}, mR[t], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Include the ability to optionally pass options to the plot.

```
plot[a_, b_, c_, ϕ_, tmax_, opts___] :=
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[mR[t] /. sol[a, b, c, ϕ, tmax][[1]]], {t, 0, tmax}, opts]
```

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to vary the parameters. For example,

```
Manipulate[
 plot[a, b, c, ϕ, tmax,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {mRx, mRy, mRz}),
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1.2}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 1.3}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ϕ, Pi}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, 100}, 10, 250, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you, Bob!